# Change -mempoolexpiry in BitcoinCore 0.20.1

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, mempool

I have accidentally made a transaction with a very low fee (5 sat/byte) and I doubt that it will be confirmed any time soon.
*Replace-By-Fee* is not available since my transaction has no change.
*Abandon the transaction* option is also not available.
How can I change the `-mempoolexpiry` setting in my BitcoinCore (0.20.1), which I run on Windows 10, so that I don't need to wait for 2 weeks for the transaction to be automatically dropped out of the mempool?

Answer (score 0):

> I have accidentally made a transaction with a very low fee (5 sat/byte) and I doubt that it will be confirmed any time soon

[image]

It may get confirmed in a few hours/days based on the fee distribution of mempool I see at https://btc.bitaps.com

> How can I change the -mempoolexpiry setting in my BitcoinCore (0.20.1), which I run on Windows 10, so that I don't need to wait for 2 weeks for the transaction to be automatically dropped out of the mempool?

It can be changed in *bitcoin.conf* file however if the transaction is already relayed to other nodes I don't think it will affect anything.

Comment: RBF doesn't technically require change, but without change, there is no way to increase the fee without decreasing the amount being sent.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this. Will edit my answer.